# SpringBoot cannot resolve path to static resources(404)

Tags: intellij-idea, spring-boot

None of the solutions to the likewise issues I've checked has worked for me. I'm using Intellij Idea Spring Initializer, which has a clear project structure:

src:
   
--- main:
         
 ---------- java:
                 
 ---------------- myproject:
                     
 ------------------------------ config
                     
 ------------------------------ controller
                     
 ------------------------------ dao
                     
 ------------------------------ model
                     
 ------------------------------ service
                     
 ------------------------------
 HibernateApplication.java

--------- resources:

--------------- static:

--------------- template

Here **HibernateApplication** is a main runner class, a standard one provided by SpringBoot and marked @SpringBootApplication; **resources** is located under the **main** directory, and, as far I see from other examples, it serves as a web-inf folder. 
In **config**, there's a @Configuration class:

```
    @Configuration
    public class AppConfig {
    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver(){
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new 
        InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/resources/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        return resolver;
    }
}
```

Here is my **@Controller** class:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class ActorController {
    @Autowired
    private ActorService actorService;

    @GetMapping
    public String addActor(){
        //actorService.addActor();
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

I'm not using here my services, all I'm trying to do is just to make him get and respond with a "**hello.jsp**" file that is lying exactly in resources/static folder. Its contents are dead simple:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hello</title>
</head>
<body>
Hello from Spring Boot!
</body>
</html>
```

Following are my **application.properties**:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sakila<br>
spring.datasource.username=root<br>
spring.datasource.password=root<br>
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop<br>
security.basic.enabled=false<br>
```

My **dependencies** include *tomcat-embded-jasper*, *jstl*, *javax.servlet* and all the necessary spring boot stuff. However, when I run localhost:8080/ I'm getting a whitelabel error page with unexpected 404 error. If my path is configured like
 .setPrefix("/resources/").setSuffix(".jsp"), it says it cannot resolve "/resources/hello.jsp". If I set prefix to ("/resources/static/"), it cannot find "/resources/static/hello.jsp".

What's the matter? Even Intellij resolves the path easily when I click Ctrl on that path and it redirects me right to "resources" folder.

P.S. OK, I've found one problem: by default Intellij has created this "myproject" folder and runner class was inside it, I've mistakenly started to add new packages inside this folder. Now I've fixed that, moving all packages out of this folder up to the 'main' folder, leaving "myproject" folder only with the runner class inside. The hierarchy now must be alright, yet still no view is returned in browser.

Comment: in the paths try removing /resources and check as spring boot defaults to resources folder

Answer (score 0):

Spotted a problem.
 1. A Thymeleaf dependency was missing.
 2. Controllers, DAO and stuff all should go as the subfolders inside the main folder with a SpringBootApplication main class. My problem was that my controller wasn't even on the component scan path.
 3. The views should be placed inside the 'templates' folder, not like in my case (mistakenly) inside 'static'. Views also (in my case) had to be html, not jsp. 
 4. Eventually I deleted ViewResolver definitions in code, since my html files were detected now by SpringBoot by default.

Thanks, the question can be closed now.